# microphone of headset picks up sound from speakers of headset

Tags: headset

I am having a problem that the microphone picks up sound from the speakers. If I turn the volume of the speakers down, then the microphone does not pick it up but then conversation is unnatural as I have to struggle to hear the other person.

I am wondering if a unidirectional microphone would solve this, or having headphones that somehow do not permit sound to get to the microphone. So I would like to ask if anyone has encountered and solved this problem.

Comment: Get a better headset.  Start by looking for one that covers the ears better so that less sound "leaks" out.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you are having a feedback problem. If so, a uni-directional mike may help, headphones will.

Answer (score 0):

A decent-quality headset with a noise-cancelling mic would probably help - and the comment suggesting "covers the ears better " (or "closed") earphones is spot on as well.

Unidirectional is not really going to solve this problem. If it's pointing at your mouth it's also effectively pointing at the earpieces (they are not all that magically-tight-beamed.)

Comment: It is Logitech H150 which says it is noise canceling

Comment: Yes, well, a ~$10 headset may not be all it claims to be. Which is why I edited my answer about 15 seconds after first submitting it solely to add "decent-quality." Decent-quality probably trumps "noise-cancelling" as a selection criterion, really.

Comment: Products vary but how can I tell before I buy? I could buy another one which claims to be noise canceling but then I risk having the same problem

Comment: Shop. Read reviews, paying attention to clues that they might not be legitimate - do they pass the smell test? Did the reviewer actually buy the product, or get given it for free? Did you see an exact copy of review at site X on site Y, etc. Price point-wise, remember that if it seems to good to be true, it's probably not true; and that cheap and inexpensive are not the same thing. Cheap can be very expensive, when it does not work and you buy 5 cheap things instead of one that costs more, but works. Buying from a place that will let you return it if it does not work right also helps...